# Boolean condition in for loop C

Tags: c, boolean-logic

The following code is intended to assert if a string contains a certain prefix.
The function `prefix`returns 1 only if the string given contains the prefix `pre`.

```
/* preprocessor directives */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* prototypes */
int prefix(char * pre, char * str);

int main() {
    /* declaration / initialization */
    char pre[] = "Hell", str1[] = "Hello!", str2[] = "hi!";
    int errCode = prefix(pre, str1);

    /* processing */
    assert (errCode == 1);
    errCode = prefix(pre, str2);
    assert (errCode == 0);

    errCode = prefix(NULL, str2);
    assert (errCode == 0);
        errCode = prefix(pre, NULL);
    assert (errCode == 0);

    /* termination */
    return 0;
}

/* Returns 0 if pre or str is NULL or if pre is not a prefix of str.
 * Otherwise returns 1.
 */
int prefix(char * pre, char * str) {
        /* declaration / initialization */
    int i;

    /* processing */
    if (pre == NULL || str == NULL) return 0;

    for (i = 0; pre[i] != '\0' || str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (pre[i] != str[i]) return 0;

    if (pre[i] != '\0') return 0;

    /* termination */
    return 1;
}
```

After compilation and running, `assert (errCode == 1)` fails.
I run it through gdb and find out that in the for loop inside `prefix` function,
the line `if (pre[i] != str[i]) return 0;` is executed even when `pre[i] == '\000'`.
Shouldn't the condition in the for loop be met at this point and this last comparison not to be executed??
I realized that changing the for condition from `||`to `&&` does what i meant in the first place, yet i do not understand why and this is my question. How come the following condition
`pre[i] != '\0' || str[i] != '\0'` is still executed when `pre[i] == '\000'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `||`..ie `logical or` which evaluates to `true` if any one of values is `true`

So for condition `pre[i] != '\0' || str[i] != '\0'`, although `pre[i]='\0'`, `str[i]!='\0'`. So condition evaluates to `true` and it enters the loop.

What you need to use is `&&`..ie `logical and`

In simple terms, **loop until both the strings are not '\0'**, This is achieved by

`pre[i] != '\0' && str[i] != '\0'`